# 'Cannot destructure property of as it is undefined' during map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was trying to make an array.map that retans an object. Some objects have a key "last_paper" and others don't. I need to pass through all the properties of this object and send them to other React component. But, not all objetcs have the key "last_paper", so when it pass through the array, my page breaks and send me this error 'Cannot destructure property of as it is undefined'. I know that the reason of the error message is the lack of the key "last_paper" in some objects but I don't know how to avoid this problem.

My component RobotContainer, robots is my array with objects.

```
{robots.map((robot) => <RobotCard key={robot.id} robot={robot} />)}
```

in my component RobotCard i try do destruct some robot props, including the last_paper. last_paper is an object too and I need some infos from this too.

```
const { id, title, last_paper } = robot;
const { paper } = last_paper;
```

still in RobotCard i try to render paper:

```
<h1>
{paper}
</h1>
```

But some of robot don't have the key last_paper i get the error in the title. If i don't have the last_paper property I just wanna render another div for example. Can you help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to destructure something that might not exist. Sounds like you need to use conditional rendering - render the `<h1>` if the property exists, and otherwise render that "another div", in whatever format you're looking for.

```
const { id, title, last_paper } = robot;
// ...

{
  last_paper
    ? <h1>{last_paper.paper}</h1>
    : <div>No paper</div>
}
```

If rendering an empty h1 in such a situation would work, you could also do just

```
const { id, title, last_paper } = robot;
// ...

<h1>{last_paper?.paper}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some option would be to provide a default value to `last_paper` when destructuring it:

```
const { paper } = last_paper ?? { paper: 'Some default value' };

or

const { paper } = last_paper ?? {} // Would default to undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{robots.map((robot) => <RobotCard key={robot.id} robot={robot} />)}
```

you send the object parent component to the child component(RobotCard) if you want an object in the child component so use **props**.
try this code: 
first: use props

```
const { id, title, last_paper } = **props.robot**;<br/>
const { paper } = last_paper 
<h4>{paper}</h4>
```

second option

```
const { id, title, last_paper } = props.robot;<br/>
const { paper } = last_paper || {}
<h4>{paper}</h4>
```

third option if second not work: -

```
const { id, title, last_paper } = robot;

<h4>{last_paper?last_paper.paper:undefined}</h4>
```